# DeadlineExceededError: The overall deadline for responding to the HTTP request was exceeded

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-platform

I have a cron job which calls vendor api to fetch the companies list. Once the data is fetched, we are storing that data into cloud datastore as  shown in the below code . For some reason  for last two days when i trigger the cron job , started seeing the errors. When i debug the code locally i dont see this error

```
    company_list = cron.rest_client.load(config, "companies", '')

    if not company_list:
        logging.info("Company list is empty")
        return "Ok"

    for row in company_list:
        company_repository.save(row,original_data_source, 
                                 actual_data_source)
```

Repository code

```
  def save( dto, org_ds , act_dp):
   try:
    key = 'FIN/%s' % (dto['ticker'])
    company = CompanyInfo(id=key)
    company.stock_code = key
    company.ticker = dto['ticker']
    company.name = dto['name']
    company.original_data_source = org_ds
    company.actual_data_provider = act_dp
    company.put()
    return company
  except Exception:
    logging.exception("company_repository: error occurred saving the 
                       company record ")
    raise
```

Error

```
  DeadlineExceededError: The overall deadline for responding to the 
                          HTTP request was exceeded.
```

Exception details

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File   

"/base/data/home/runtimes/python27_experiment/python27_lib/versions/1/googl
    e/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 267, in Handle
    result = handler(dict(self._environ), self._StartResponse)
   File "/base/data/home/apps/p~svasti-173418/internal-
  api:20170808t160537.403249868819304873/lib/flask/app.py", line 1836, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "/base/data/home/apps/p~svasti-173418/internal-
   api:20170808t160537.403249868819304873/lib/flask/app.py", line 1817, in 
    wsgi_app
      response = self.full_dispatch_request()
    File "/base/data/home/apps/p~svasti-173418/internal-
   api:20170808t160537.403249868819304873/lib/flask/app.py", line 1475, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/base/data/home/apps/p~svasti-173418/internal-api:20170808t160537.403249868819304873/lib/flask/app.py", line 1461, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/base/data/home/apps/p~svasti-173418/internal-api:20170808t160537.403249868819304873/internal/cron/company_list.py", line 21, in run
    company_repository.save(row,original_data_source, actual_data_source)
  File "/base/data/home/apps/p~svasti-173418/internal-api:20170808t160537.403249868819304873/internal/repository/company_repository.py", line 13, in save
    company.put()
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27_experiment/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/ndb/model.py", line 3458, in _put
    return self._put_async(**ctx_options).get_result()
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27_experiment/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/ndb/tasklets.py", line 383, in get_result
    self.check_success()
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27_experiment/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/ndb/tasklets.py", line 378, in check_success
    self.wait()
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27_experiment/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/ndb/tasklets.py", line 362, in wait
    if not ev.run1():
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27_experiment/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/ndb/eventloop.py", line 268, in run1
    delay = self.run0()
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27_experiment/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/ndb/eventloop.py", line 248, in run0
    _logging_debug('rpc: %s.%s', rpc.service, rpc.method)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27_experiment/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/api/apiproxy_stub_map.py", line 453, in service
    @property
DeadlineExceededError: The overall deadline for responding to the HTTP request was exceeded.
```

Answer (score 3):

Has your company list been getting bigger?

How many entities are you trying to put?

Try saving them as a batch, instead of sequentially in a loop. Remove `company.put()` from `def save( dto, org_ds , act_dp):` and use `ndb.put_multi()` afterwards instead.

```
company_list = cron.rest_client.load(config, "companies", '')

if not company_list:
    logging.info("Company list is empty")
    return "Ok"

company_objs=[]
for row in company_list:
    company_objs.append(company_repository.save(row,original_data_source, 
                             actual_data_source))
    # put 500 at a time
    if len(company_objs) > 500:
        ndb.put_multi(company_objs)
        company_objs=[]
# put any remainders
if len(company_objs) > 0:
    ndb.put_multi(company_objs)
```

Comment: there are around 6000 stocks

Comment: That's a fair amount, that's getting to the point where you may want to mapreduce this thing. I modified my answer to put 500 at a time. In my experience ndb can sometimes hang when using put_multi / get_multi on more than 1000 objects

Answer (score 2):

My answer is based on one that Alex gave, but runs [async](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/ndb/async).

I've replaced `put_multi()` with `put_multi_async()`

> By replacing the call to `put_multi()` with a call to its async equivalent `put_multi_async()`, the application can do other things right away instead of blocking on `put_multi()`.

And added `@ndb.toplevel` decorator

> This decorator tells the handler not to exit until its asynchronous requests have finished

If your data grows bigger, you may want to look deeper into [defered library](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/articles/deferred). It can be used to respawn task every X batches, with the rest of your unprocessed data.

```
@ndb.toplevel
def fetch_companies_list():
    company_list = cron.rest_client.load(config, "companies", '')

    if not company_list:
        logging.info("Company list is empty")
        return "Ok"

    company_objs=[]
    for row in company_list:
        company_objs.append(company_repository.save(row,original_data_source, 
                             actual_data_source))
        # put 500 at a time
        if len(company_objs) >= 500:
            ndb.put_multi_async(company_objs)
            company_objs=[]
    # put any remainders
    if len(company_objs) > 0:
        ndb.put_multi_async(company_objs)
```

Comment: @DanCornilescu how about spawning task queue for each put ?. Since i will be loading 6000 records it will be 6000 task queues

Comment: That would work, too - using the task queue is not as simple, but it is more flexible/scalable IMHO. But it might appear overkill if the amount of work to do for each company is very small, in which case maybe processing a batch per task may be better. Either way, one thing to be careful about in such case is using a progressively longer `delay` at task creation to not suddenly throw a pile of immediately executable tasks at your app, which could cause many dynamic instances to be started, potentially expensive.

Comment: @Pythonist isn't this the same as doing `ndb.put_multi()` on the entire batch of 6000? I thought `ndb.put_multi()` was just a convenience function for calling `.put_async()` on multiple entities.